# Finding the space adventure story in the late 1970's or earlier

Tags: story-identification, space-exploration

I've read an interesting story in the late 90's, but the book was already 20 years old. So the story was written earlier than 1970's.

What I recall about it:

- All starts with some kind of sorting machine similar to the one in the *Profession* story by Asimov.
- It's a sci-fi story about space adventures and hyperspace travel.
- And last thing that I remember, there was a lousy auction for the main hero, where they bought a worst possible planet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be [Sargasso of Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargasso_of_Space) by Andre Norton?